# Расчет удвоенной задержки распространения сигнала(PDV)

Tags: сеть, маршрутизация

Левый сегмент - 450м, маршрутизатор, правый сегмент - 180м.
Кабель - 100Base-FX(многомодовое оптоволокно - полный дуплекс).
Для такого волокна максимальная длина - 2000м, задержка на 1м - 1.0bt .

Но при рассчете PDV получаю:
PDV = 450 * 1.0bt + 180 * 1.0bt + 100(2 адаптера FX) + 140(повторитель класса 1) = 870bt

что куда больше разрешенных 512bt. Итак, если оптоволокно позволяет длину до 2км, то где я ошибся?

Comment: задержка на 1м - 1.0bt. Не перепутали, вроде бы 0,1bt на 1м.

Comment: Вот не знаю, написано во всех мануалах, что для Ethernet - 0.1bt, а вот так как Fast Ethernet в 10 раз быстрее, для него и задержка в 10 раз больше. Таким образом, выходит, что максимальная длина сегмента - 412 метров, но ведь оптоволокно можно пускать и до 2 км.

Comment: Нет, не так, 0,1 это не для Etherneta а для соеды в которой он бегает а именно в 100Base-FX, пересчитай свою формулу подставив туда 0,1.

Comment: С 0.1bt все норм :)

Comment: Проверяйте всё, что до оптоволокна, кабель-тестером! Возможно, что несколько соединений в кабеле (или в коннекторах) отвалились.

Comment: @areshin здесь кажется просто задание на расчет... Обучение типа...

Answer (score 1):

Расчёт применим в среде с хабами ("повторитель класса...") для предотвращения возникновения коллизий. Т.о., даже с коммутаторами этот расчёт применять нельзя, не говоря про маршрутизаторы.